# Associate the chart and table in devextreme

Tags: mongodb, charts, datagrid, mean-stack, devextreme

I want to associate the table and chart in devextreme.  I want to filter the chart also filter the table.  **can you help me?**

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using filter option of related datasource

```
function chartFilter(ChartInstance, ChartKey, KeyValue, ReloadChartsFunc) {

/*
   ChartInstance = Instance of devExtreme Chart
   ChartKey = filter by ChartKey Field 
   KeyValue = value of ChartKey
   ReloadChartsFunc = Callback function to execute once filter the ds
*/



var searchOperator = "<>";
if (KeyValue != "")
    searchOperator = psChart.option("quickSearchOption");


var ds = ChartInstance.getDataSource();
ds.filter(ChartKey, searchOperator, KeyValue);


ds.load().done(function (result) {

 if (ReloadChartsFunc != undefined && result[0] != undefined && result[0] != null) {

     ReloadChartsFunc(result[0])
 }
 });

}
```

You can do whatever you want to modify the above code according to your need.